# reading pairs of data from a file

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I am trying to read pairs of data from a file using the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
//**** Opening data file ****   

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("reg_data_log.inp");

    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File successfully open" << endl;

    }
    else
    {
    cout << "Error opening file";
    }

//**** Reading data ***

    vector<pair<double, double> > proteins;

    pair<double, double> input;

    while (infile >> input.first >> input.second) 
    {
        proteins.push_back(input);
    }

//**** Show data in screen ****

    cout << "Proteins analized: " << proteins.size() << endl;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<proteins.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i.first << ", " << i.second << endl;
    }

}
```

when compiling I have the following message

> "65:13: error: request for member ‘first’ in ‘i’, which is of non-class type ‘unsigned int’"
>       "65:13: error: request for member ‘first’ in ‘i’, which is of non-class type ‘unsigned int’"

I cannot get my head around the problem.  Can anybody help?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You use `i` in that last loop. It is an `int`. Yet you try to access `i.first`.

Comment: You need to use an iterator. Ex: `for (auto i : proteins) {cout << i.first << ", " << i.second << endl;}`

Comment: the iterator give me a compiler error  63:7: warning: ‘auto’ changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]

Comment: @berkboy are you on a pre c++11 compiler?

Comment: re. "‘auto’ changes meaning": upgrade your compiler or use `-std=c++11` compilation flag (could be `-std=c++0x` in your version if it's very old).

Comment: @Paul Rooney i am using "g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4"

Answer (score 2):

Look further at your loop

```
for(unsigned int i=0; i<proteins.size(); i++)
{
    cout << i.first << ", " << i.second << endl;
}
```

You are trying to access the property `first` of the integer value `i`. integers do not have that property it is a property of a `pair` object.

I think you are getting confused between iterating using iterator and indices. The simple fix is to use a range based for loop, as already suggested in comments.

```
for(auto d: proteins)
{
    cout << d.first << ", " << d.second << endl;
}
```

Now what you have as is the element from the vector and not an integer. You can now access `first` and `second`.

If you cannot use range based for loop and `auto`, then you can use the old iterator for loop way.

```
for(vector<pair<double, double> >::iterator it = proteins.begin();
    it != proteins.end();
    ++it)
{
    cout << it->first << ", " << it->second << endl;
}
```

and someone else has already posted the how it can be done using indices, so I won't repeat that here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I see my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As [John Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp) mentions in his comment, indeed you arev referencing an int and not a pair-type. The following loop will most likely fix your issues:

```
cout << "Proteins analized: " << proteins.size() << endl;

for(unsigned int i=0; i<proteins.size(); i++)
{
    cout << proteins[i].first << ", " << proteins[i].second << endl;
}
```

I did not test this yet, but I am pretty convinced this solves your problem.